# Deployed Web-App but no folder within webapps

Tags: tomcat, war

I have a WAR that I wish to deploay on a Tomcat. As this file is quite big (some 150MB) I simply dropped it into `/usr/share/Tomcat7/webapps` to autodeploy it when server is restarted. After re-starting tomcat the app was deployed correctly, I may access the app using `http://myhost:8080/myApp`. However there is no such folder under `webapps/myApp` containing the files building up the app, the archieve-file is still there.

So I wonder how I change any file within that webapp (e.g. the config file under `webapps/myApp/WEB-INF`) if the appropriate folder doesn´t even exist. Or is the webapp unpacked in any other folder which I´m not aware of?

This is my `server.xml`-file:

```
<Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener" SSLEngine="on"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener"/>
    <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>

    <GlobalNamingResources>
        <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container" type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
            description="User database that can be updated and saved"
            factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
            pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml"/>
    </GlobalNamingResources>
    <Service name="Catalina">


    <Executor name="tomcatThreadPool" namePrefix="catalina-exec-" maxThreads="1024"
            minSpareThreads="4"/>

    <Connector executor="tomcatThreadPool" port="80" connectionTimeout="20000"
            redirectPort="443" protocol="org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol"/>

    <Connector port="443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true" maxThreads="150" scheme="https"
            secure="true" clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLS" keystoreFile="conf/certificate.jks"
            keystoreType="JKS" keystorePass="ciardi25" keyPass="ciardi25"/>

    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">    
        <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
                    resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
            </Realm>

            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true"
                startStopThreads="0">

                <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                    prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
                    pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b"/>

            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
</Server>
```

EDIT: `catalina.out` also states, that the app has successfully been deployed as there are many comments within the file that have been written by my app.

EDIT: OS is Amazon Linux AMI

Comment: At first glance your configuration seems correct. Did you check the log files for any errors?

Comment: Nothing meaningful considdering `catalina.out`. The webapp writes some messages to log-file that confirm it has been set up and it is working correctly. Only thing I see is some warning complaining `An attempt was made to authenticate the locked user "root"` (for `admin`, `manager` and `tomcat` accordingly).

Comment: Not sure what flavour of Unix you are on but on Ubuntu I usually drop the war file under `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps/`. I read somewhere that the directory makes a difference. So you could try that.

Comment: For this I should GET a directory first I guess. But there is none, so deleting the WAR will probably delete the app itself, won´t it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Tomcat has been installed via some package manager, its files are usually spread across serveral dirs, like `/usr/share/tomcatX/`, `/var/lib/tomcatX/`, and `/etc/tomcatX`.

If your packages have been deployed with `apt`, you might try `dpkg-query -L tomcat7` to see all paths belonging to the installation. With `rpm`, it's `rpm -ql tomcat7`. From the output, you can determine which dir is actually part of the installation, and which is not.

There is a Debian installation here, which has its `webapps` folder in `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps`. Maybe you should check if this directory contains your webapp as well. Why Tomcat appears to nupack the WARs to a different folder yet remains mysterious. Are you using some `/etc/init.d/tomcat7` for starting/stopping it? If so, you might want to take a look at that script and what it does on startup.

Comment: Indeed Tomcat seems to be seperated into different directories. However also `/var/lib/tomcat7/webapps` only contains the archieve instead of the actual folder.

Comment: Strange. I would recommend searching it the hard way: `find /etc /opt /tmp /usr /var -iname myapp -type d`.

Comment: Found the app under `var/cache/tomcat7/work/Catalina/localhost/myApp`. Why does Tomcat deploay to that directory?

Comment: Too happy too soon. Whilst the folder exists under the mentioned path only its JSP-files are contained and the classes used by the app. No deploay-ment-descriptor (`web.xml`) nor any any other file

Comment: Not surprisingly - the `work` folder is used internally to hold persisted session data and compiled JSP classes. I heard Tomcat can also run a webapp directly from a WAR file without unpacking it, yet never verified if it's possible. What happens if you 1) remove the WAR, 2) stop Tomcat, 3) unpack it manually to `webapps/`, and 4) start Tomcat again?

Comment: Last time I tired this out the whole machine stopped working, so I intend not to repeat this

Comment: No risk no fun ;-) What I mean is: Why not unpack the WAR on your own, if Tomcat does not do it the way you want to? `unzip` is your friend.

Comment: Well, unpacking using `unzip` worked (however I did it before using `jar` which crahsed my machine). I get a new error on some new JSP-files within the app, however I consider this as new topic. Thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome! I regret I could not spot the exact cause of your problems, but sometimes a cumbersome solution is better than none.